# Listbox doesn't display database names

Tags: c#, database, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox control in my winform.

The data that I am trying to display is from a databse called **names.accdb**
The database has a column called **custName** and the name of the table is **names**

I am trying to display the list of customer names in the listbox, but it is not working.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    comboBox1.Items.Add("(M)");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("(F)");
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

    OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
    connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                                        Data Source=C:\Users\Student\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Pract2\Pract2\Names.accdb";

    connect.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT custName FROM names", connect);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    listBox1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Set `listBox1.DisplayMember = "custName";`

Comment: Fine, "it is not working" means what? are you getting any error?

Comment: Did you execute this query on its own? What results are you getting?

Comment: any exceptions? Have you tried to debug your code and see if dt (your DataTable) is already empty?

Comment: @un-lucky no I am not getting any errors

Comment: @Alex yes I have an it works properly but on the win form it doesnt

Comment: I also tried it using the Use Data Bound Items under the List Box tasks and it works properly and the names are displayed but when using the method above the form loads but no names are displayed

Comment: When you can't see anything in `ListBox` it means there is no data in `DataTable`. But when you see the `System.Data.DataRowView` string in all items of list, it's because of not setting `DisplayMember` for `ListBox`.

Comment: The most obvious problem in your code is you bind the `ListBox` to a `DataTable` but you didn't tell to the `ListBox` to show which column of table. You should set [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `ListBox` to the column name of `DataTable`which you want to show in list. As I said in previous comment: 

    `listBox1.DisplayMember = "custName";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the  [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) that Gets or sets the property to display for this ListControl.

```
listBox1.DataSource = dt;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "custName";
```

Comment: it still  doesnt display anything I'm afraid